# Trying to add a number to a variable in Python, keeps resetting the variable back to what it was originally

Tags: python, function

```
def start():
    number = 0
    prompt = raw_input("> ")
    if prompt == "1":
        number += 1
        print number
        start()

    else:
        start()

start()
```

My output:

```
Enter Number: 1
1
Enter Number: 1
1
Enter Number: 1
1
```

I've had this problem when using `+=` before, and the same thing happens if I try `number = number + 1`. How can I make the number actually add?

I'm guessing that when it goes back to `start()` after adding the number, it resets on the `number = 0` line. How can I stop this?

Comment: FYI you can just use `input` instead of `raw_input`and in your function 1 doesn't have to be in quotes since `input` returns a float

Comment: That's useful to know, thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

You're recursively calling `start()`. Within each successive call, you create a variable `number` in the namespace with value `0`. The problem is that you're adding to a new variable each time, not an initial value of `number` that's set to `0` once.

You can fix this by using a global variable that's defined once. Like so:

```
number = 0

def start():
    prompt = raw_input("> ")
    if prompt == "1":
        global number
        number += 1
        print number
    start()

start()
```

However, global variables are bad, and there's really no need for recursion here. Why not use the following?

```
number = 0
while True:
    prompt = raw_input("> ")
    if prompt == "1":
        number += 1
    print number
```

Comment: I tried setting 'number = 0' outside the function to see if that would help, instead I get 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'number' referenced before assignment'. What could this mean?

Comment: Within the function, it's looking for a local variable by the name of `number`, but one does not exist. If you define one globally (i.e. at the top level, outside the function), the statement `global number` means to look at this level for such a variable, not within the function. You should [read up on namespaces](http://bytebaker.com/2008/07/30/python-namespaces/), it will help clarify things for you.

Comment: In a sentence, you get that error because `number` is out of [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(programming)).

Comment: While in this particular program, there is definitely no need for recursion. However, I'm just testing for something I want to make later, that will require it to repeat and allow me to input another number. Is there a way to do this? And thanks for the help, it's been useful :P

Comment: Yes, there's certainly a way to do that (I'd probably still stick with a while loop that you `break` out of with some event). I'd recommend opening a new question with your new question & code when that time comes.